# Grapevine REST server , I could not reach from other PC with IP or host name

Tags: c#, rest, http, server, grapevine

I am using VS2012 and Grapevine 3.0.4 , when i use the Grapevine same machine with localhost 
hostname , everything works well.
If I want to reach from other PC with client , Server could not be start listening with hostname ip address or Computername

If i try server pc set hostname to localhost , it starts listening but when reached from other PC with IP or name server returns bad request 400

Is it something wrong with my code or library.

My Server code is

```
public class embeddedHTTP
{
    private RESTServer Server;

    public void ServerStart()
    {
        try
        {
            Server = new RESTServer();
            Server.Port =  GlobalVars.HttpHostPort;
            Server.Host = GlobalVars.HttpHostAdress; // THIS ONLY WORKS FOR LOCALHOST
            Server.MaxThreads = 20;
            Server.Start();

            while (Server.IsListening)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(GlobalVars.HttpHostRespTime);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messenger.logque("embedded HTTP server not started, Error ID : 52", 3, null);
        }
    }

    public void ServerStop()
    {
        Server.Stop();
    }

    public sealed class MyResource : RESTResource
    {    
        //d+$^  [a-zA-Z]+
        [RESTRoute(Method = Grapevine.HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = @"/")] 
        public void HandleFooRequests(HttpListenerContext context)
        {    
            //String RawuR = context.Request.RawUrl;
            String URL = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Url);
            String ResultXML = brain.HTTPCMD(URL);          
            this.SendTextResponse(context, ResultXML);    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction : VS2015 community Edition

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reach the server from a remote machine, you are likely running a firewall that is blocking inbound traffic to the port you are listening on. Try opening the port on your firewall, and see if that works for you.

[How to Open a Port in the Windows 7 Firewall](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html)

Also, you can listen on all hosts by using the asterisk (*) as your hostname.